# Makefile: rule to zcompile all .zwc files

Tags: shell, makefile, zsh

I have directory `functions` containing `zsh` function definitions, as well as compiled version of each function:

```
ls functions/*
functions/foo functions/foo.zwc functions/bar functions/bar.zwc
```

Now I need a `make` rule, if file `foo` changed, compile `foo.zwc` again.

I know how to specify rule for each file individually"

```
functions/foo.zwc: functions/foo
    zsh -c 'zcompile functions/foo.zwc functions/foo'
```

but how do I generalize that, so that if any `*.zwc` file in that directory changed, I recompile it? I have something half working, but it always echoes all `zwc` files, regardless whether the corresponding file changed or not:

```
file := $(wildcard functions/*.zwc)

$(file): %.zwc: %
    @echo file = $(file)
```

also, how do I use the file name variable inside my zsh command  ?

```
zsh -c 'zcompile .....'
```

## UPDATE:

based on the answer, I have created this makefile:

```
FILES = $(filter-out $(wildcard functions/*.zwc), $(wildcard functions/*))

all: ${FILES}

functions/%: functions/%.zwc
    zsh -c 'zcompile $< $@'
```

However, the problem is, it runs every time for each file, even if `file` has not changed since `file.zwc` has been generated last time.

What is wrong with my make rule?
How do i only generate `file.zwc` only when the underlying `file` has changed?

Answer (score 1):

```
SRCS = $(wildcard  functions/*.zwc)
TARGETS = $(SRCS:.zwc=)

all: ${TARGETS}
    @echo "DONE"

functions/%: functions/%.zwc
    @echo $(notdir $@)
```

Comment: thanks, but how do I use the command `zsh -c 'zcompile functions/foo.zwc functions/foo'` with the variable file name, instead of just the echo command?

Comment: `<whatever-cmd-you-want> $(notdir $@).zwc $(notdir $@)` ... add `functions/` if necessary, or remove the `$(notdir ...)`

Comment: You can also `zsh -c 'zcompile $< $@'`.